# how to write bash && & in one line

Tags: linux, shell

how to write this in one line ?

```
reboot -d 5 -f &  ;echo 666
```

then it tells me

```
-sh: syntax error: unexpected ";"
```

I use follow replace before to test to avoid reboot and easy to test

```
 echo 555 & ; echo 666
-sh: syntax error: unexpected ";
```

I have try others

```
[root@EPC-M6Y2C ~]# `echo 555 & `&&  echo 666
-sh: 555: not found
[root@EPC-M6Y2C ~]# `echo 555 & ` ;  echo 666
-sh: 555: not found
666
```

Comment: `shutdown -r now 666`

Answer (score 2):

Both `&` and `;` terminate lists. `&` causes the list to run in the background, `;` in the foreground.

If you use both, the `&` terminates the list and the `;` tries to terminate an empty list, which is not allowed.

Just drop the `;`:

```
reboot -d 5 -f & echo 666
```

Answer (score 1):

You would get the same error if you just wrote an isolated

```
;
```

For the same reason, you can not write i.e. `echo x;;echo y`. If you want to write an empty statement (no-op), use `:` as a placeholder, i.e.

```
echo x; :; echo y
```

works fine. In your case, this would be

```
reboot -d 5 -f & : ;echo 666
```

However, I would simply drop the no-op and write

```
reboot -d 5 -f & echo 666
```